# What is the meaning of these lines in Albee's Three Tall Women?

Tags: meaning, edward-albee, three-tall-women

Can anyone please let me know the meaning of the following lines taken from Edward Albee's play *Three Tall Women*. The lines are spoken by character A, an elderly woman, expressing her view of the "happiest moment" of the life which she means to be the time of death. My problem is particularly with the part specified in bold.

> "Coming to the end of it, I think, **when all the waves cause the greatest woes to subside, leaving breathing space**, time to concentrate on the greatest woe of all—that blessed one—the end of it"

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Are you having trouble with understanding the meaning of this passage, or just with finding other words to express the same meaning? The former is definitely in-scope for this site, as it's about understanding a work of literature, but the latter would be more a language problem than a literature one IMO. (I didn't downvote this btw.)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I actually thought to include it here as it is related to literature, but yes I may shift the question to language website. But I think the question might somehow be related to both areas.

Comment: What *is* the question, exactly? Do you need help understanding the meaning, or do you just want an alternative wording?

Comment: No I don't need an alternative wording. I need to know the meaning especially behind the words in bold.

Comment: Ah, in that case it's definitely OK for this site :-) I've edited to make that more clear. I suspect the downvote (and also a close-vote as "too broad") are from someone who thought you were asking for a paraphrase when you already knew the meaning. Asking for help understanding the meaning of a passage is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "all the waves" here refers to the passage of time, which is made up of one thing ("wave") after another. With the passage of time, even the "greatest woes" lose their power of immediacy, leaving a space of calm ("breathing space") in which one may contemplate death.